# Difference in variable handling between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, firefox

I have a problem with Javascript variables that only occurs in firefox and not in chrome.

```
<input id="test" type="file"/>
<script>
    var f = document.getElementById('test').files;
    var value = f;
    var i = setInterval(() => {
        f = document.getElementById('test').files;
        if (f == value) {
            console.log(true);
            console.log(f);
            console.log(value);
        } else {
            console.log(false);
            console.log(f);
            console.log(value);
            value = f;
            clearInterval(i);
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

this code keeps putting true in the console log and is supposed to track variable changes.
in chrome, if i choose a file with the file input tag. it will track the variable difference between variable 'value' and variable 'f'. this will cause it to console.log(false) and terminate the setInterval.  however, in firefox after selecting a file with the file input both variables are instantly updated and firefox wont be able to track any differences. causing the script to never end.

heres a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y9jh6a1t/

i wish to replicate chromes behaviour in firefox.

Comment: `var f = document.getElementById('test').files;;` Taking out the extra semi here might help. They tend to handle buggy things like this a bit differently.

Comment: @Jbluehdorn oof that was just a typo. but that wasnt the cause of the problem. sharp eye tho

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure then. Though I would change your code to use the `onChange` handler for the input instead of polling every second. It'll respond quicker and take less overhead.

Comment: @Jbluedhorn yes i'd love to change to an onchange function. but this code is simply a recreation of a part from a framework and i want to find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do you use two semicolon on the end instruction:

```
var f = document.getElementById('test').files;;
```

The browser's (Firefox and Chrome), implements two different interpreters, Firefox(SpyderMonkey) and Chrome(v8). Then, could have rules accept from Chrome and not accept from Firefox, or contrariwise.

To prevent bug's, fix the line arrive and come back to debug.

Note: I tested your snippet and removed the double semicolon (**;;**). This works for me.

Good code.

Comment: i had already updated the code and the snippet and it still doesnt work in firefox.
by the way, this code is a reproduction of a part of a mini framework. the semi colon was just a typo made by me while reconstructing. my bad

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will satisfy your condition. But instead of files, use files.length.

```
var f = document.getElementById('test').files.length;
    var value = f;
    var i = setInterval(() => {
        f = document.getElementById('test').files.length;
        if (f == value) {
            console.log(true);
            console.log(f);
            console.log(value);
        } else {
            console.log(false);
            console.log(f);
            console.log(value);
            value = f;
            clearInterval(i);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: hmm, i thought of this. but what if a person selects a particular file. and then select another file. the counter would remain on 1 and wouldnt trigger the second time. but i already found a workaround. thx for the reply mate!